# Flagging content

Tags: discussion, flagging

I did a flagged an answer once as : **Low Quality**, but the flag was declined with the comment:

> "- flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an
>   altogether wrong answer"

I then made a flag, let's have an example as this answer:

[Error in SharePoint hosted app: Add permission level to the list programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89849/error-in-sharepoint-hosted-app-add-permission-level-to-the-list-programmaticall/203720#203720)

But this time, I was hesitated to make it as Low Quality because I thought it would have been rejected, the answer was without codeblocks, and just two lines of code, with no explanation whatsoever, so rather than flagging it as low quality, I thought I might let the admins have a look at it by flagging it as: **"in need of moderator intervention "**, but it was declined with the comment:

> "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that
>   requires their intervention"

So if I see an answer like the one I saw, I should just let it there? Because it is clearly a low quality post, but right now I have just decided not to flag anything, and to just vote down on posts like that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for an answer like that, that do actually answer the question (but not with a lot of explanations) and that also already has gotten a comment about it lacking details, we as moderators should not take any further action on it.

The answer is helpful, if not to all. The need for further explanation has already been addressed.

What you can do is this case is to clarify how the answer can be improved, combined with a down-vote if you feel that it is seriously lacking in quality. Or, even better, take it upon you to improve the answer or post a more detailed one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but when I flagged it, it didn't have any comment or anything, so I thought I might refer it to the mods to have a look at it. I added the explanation on why I think it needs intervention, but yet, the flag was denied..